# Does .Any with a predicate have to generate the resulting list before it looks for .Any

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq-to-objects

I've got a List with 1,000,000 complex objects.  I need to create another list with a subset of those objects, keeping the original list unchanged.  At this point in the code, I know for certain that bigList is not null, and that it has at least 1 item.

My original code:

```
var smallList = bigList.Where(csvrec => csvrec.PreApprovalAmount <= 0 || csvrec.PreApprovalAmount > csvrec.ReplacementAmount).ToList();
```

My team lead said that there were several problems with my code.  He said that .Where could result in null, and that calling .ToList() would cause a null exception.  So, in order to avoid that, he said I needed to change my code to:

```
var smallList = new List<CSVLines>();
if(bigList.Any(csvrec => csvrec.PreApprovalAmount <= 0 || csvrec.PreApprovalAmount > csvrec.ReplacementAmount))
{
    smallList = bigList.Where(csvrec => csvrec.PreApprovalAmount <= 0 || csvrec.PreApprovalAmount > csvrec.ReplacementAmount).ToList();
}
```

1. I don't think that .Where can ever result in a null exception.
2. I don't think that smallList will not ever be null.  It could be a
   list with 0 elements, but not null.
3. Doing .Any with a predicate means it has to generate the list, then
   determine if it has at least 1 element, and then my code will have
   to generate the same list again to assign it to smallList.

Am I correct?  Are the proposed changes from my team lead basically doubling the amount of work to create this list with no real benefit?

Comment: Well first of all, what is `bigList`?

Comment: bigList is a List<CSVLine> which is a just an object with about 50 properties.

Comment: `Where` will not never produce null as output (it throws `NullReferenceException` if source collection is null), only empty IEnumerable, which translates into empty list if `Tolist` called

Comment: Your team lead is incorrect and your original code good.

Comment: `.Any` will not produce any list, it just enumerates source collection until condition is met

Comment: Where() should work. `ToList()` on larger objects is probably not a good idea. Try to stay with `IEnumerable` and limit your use of Lists.

Comment: If team lead *say* you something like this always [ask `why` 5 times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/5_Whys). He is a human and he could have a brain short-circuit.

Comment: Team leaders usually do not have all the answers to everything. A good team leader can also admit when he / she say or do something wrong. Let your team leader read this question. If they reply with "I was wrong, you where right" (or anything along these lines) then good. If they get pissed off about you undermining their authority, Then perhaps it's time to look for a new team leader.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does .Any with a predicate have to generate the resulting list before
>   it looks for .Any

No, [`Enumerable.Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx) does not need to do that. MSDN:

> The enumeration of source is stopped as soon as the result can be
>   determined.

The method takes a sequence and a predicate, then enumerates the sequence until the predicate matches once and returns `true`. If no item matches `false` is returned. So if the first item already matches the result does not need to be enumerated. In [Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,6a1af7c3d17845e3,references)-code:

```
foreach (TSource element in source) {
    if (predicate(element)) return true;
}
return false;
```

---

> Are the proposed changes from my team lead basically doubling the
>   amount of work to create this list with no real benefit?

Yes, first checking if any item matches and then using `Where` to filter is unnecessary overhead in this case. It is not doubling the overhead because `Any` stops at the first matching but it is overhead (it's doubled if there is no matching item, because the sequence has to be enumerated twice).

---

> `.Where` could result in null, and that calling .ToList() would cause
>   a `null` exception.

No, that's impossible. `Enumerable.Where` never returns `null`, it's a filter on the input sequence and if no item matches the predicate `Enumerable.Empty<T>` is returned.

Maybe he was confused because a query gets executed at the `ToList`, so if there was a `NullReferenceException` somewhere in the query, then you see this exception at the `ToList`(or any other method that executes it). Look at following query that throws an exception:

```
var query = "foo".Select(c => { throw new NullReferenceException(); return 1; });
List<int> list = query.ToList(); // exception here not in first line
```

Answer (score 3):

> He said that `.Where` could result in `null`, and that calling `.ToList()` would cause a null exception.

The only reason a `Where` could cause a null reference exception is if its target is `null` or its predicate runs into a null reference exception. If nothing matches, `.Where` returns an empty `IEnumerable<T>`, not a `null`.

Adding a call to `Any` is completely superfluous. Although it does not recreate the entire list, it still uses some CPU cycles in evaluating the predicate before returning `true` or `false`. It is still O(n), though, so when no match is found, the condition is evaluated for the entire sequence.

Adding a call to `Any` also decreases readability of your code, which is arguably worse than wasting CPU cycles.

Answer (score 0):

`.Where()` should only cause an exception if `bigList` was null to begin with.

However, doing `.Any()` does not have to generate the list. It will go through a collection and stop as soon as *first* item that matches the predicate is found.

The one change you probably should make is to remove the `ToList()` call. Try to stick with `IEnumerable` as much as possible and avoid creating the List objects, especially when working with larger sets. This is to improve memory use and avoid causing OutOfMemoryExceptions rather than NullReferenceExceptions.

Comment: `.Where` will produce exception, not `null`. As for `ToList()` we don't know what is going to happen next to follow this advice.

Comment: That's what I meant :/ Need moar coffee.

Comment: Oh, and I stand by my IEnumerable comment. He might have other code that assumes a List, but if so it's likely worthwhile to refactor to allow IEnumerable. It's _possible_ that List makes sense in his context instead of IEnumerable, but that would be the exception. Far too often it's just assumed you need a List, when all you're really doing is shooting yourself in the foot performance-wise. In this case, with potentially a large number of items, ToList() is likey creating memory holes as it uses intermediate buffers to build the final result that will eventually cause OutOfMemoryExceptions.